# How to generate n string (ie. twenty) from pattern?

Tags: bash, random

Now I'm using this code

`tr -dc 'A-X0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c12 > test.txt`

and works fine but it generate only one string without any pattern.

How to modify this string to generate n string (ie. twenty) starting with: "MyPassword" and then 12 generated digits?

thanks!

Comment: BTW, be careful here -- in some locales, characters are ordered `AaBbCc...Zz` instead of `abc...zABC...Z`, so you can have `A-X` contain lower-case characters when it's run by someone with different language settings. It's safer to have your code run `LC_COLLATE=C tr ...` to force ASCII character ordering if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 2):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        len = split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX0123456789", ary, "")
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            str = ""
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                str = str ary[int(rand() * len + 1)]
            }
            print "MyPassword" str
        }
    }
'
```

- It first generates an array `ary` which holds characters from `A` to `9`.
- The value `int(rand() * len + 1)` randomly indexes a character in the array.
- The innermost loop repeats 12 times to concatenate 12 random characters.

**[Update]**

If you prefer to use `/dev/urandom` due to its good nature of randomness, please try instead:

```
digit=12        # number of characters
number=20       # number of repetitions

awk -v digit="$digit" '
    BEGIN {
        len = split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX0123456789", ary, "")
    }
    {
        str = str ary[int(($0 / 2 ** 16) * len + 1)]
        if (++c >= digit) {
            print "MyPassword" str
            str = ""
            c = 0
        }
    }
' < <(od -vAn --width=2 -tu2 -N$(( digit * number * 2)) < /dev/urandom)
```

- It generates a sequence of 16-bit random integers by using `/dev/urandom`
  and `od`.
- Then the output of `od` is fed to the `awk` script converting the random
  numbers to random characters.

Comment: Important caveat from the documentation: *In most awk implementations, including `gawk`, `rand()` starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk.* -- so taking entropy from `/dev/urandom` is certainly the safer approach from the perspective of quality-of-entropy. Then again, you should certainly be able to write code in awk that uses `/dev/urandom`'s contents much more efficiently than the `tr` hack.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my answer with the `/dev/urandom` version.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So you want to say that using this second updated script `/ dev / urandom` my results will be more non-repeatable and using the first script I will get more duplicates?

Comment: A single-seed PRNG always has a cycle (though with better ones it's a very long cycle), and someone who can figure out the seed can completely reproduce all its output. With `rand()`, the standard doesn't offer any guarantees about how it's seeded (meaning for some implementations the seed will be completely constant; for others, it might be something like the time, that attackers can try to guess), or how long the cycle is. With `/dev/urandom`, there are often hardware sensors mixing in new entropy over time, so the state changes before it can get around to repeating itself.

Comment: ...so yes, your above comment was an accurate summary. :)

Answer (score 1):

One nicely explicit approach is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh

num_chars=12
num_strings=20

for ((i=0; i<num_strings; i++)); do
  IFS= read -r -d '' -n "$num_chars" chars && [[ $chars ]] || break
  printf 'MyPassword%s\n' "$chars"
done < <(tr -dc 'A-X0-9' < /dev/urandom)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, but 1. It  takes too long when I increased the number of characters and repetitions :( my command seems to work faster but i'm not sure for 100%, 2. one more thing how to add pattern (MyPassword) in this command at the beginning of the line for every generated string?

Comment: (1) - If you wanted to be _efficient_, you wouldn't use `tr` at all -- it throws away any characters that don't exist in the desired range. Better is to convert your data _into_ the relevant range so you're only capturing as much entropy as you need, though once you're trying to do things *right* as opposed to *quickly*, bash is no longer a well-chosen tool for the job. (2) - `printf 'MyPassword%s\n' "$chars"`